# Can I add more than one AsyncTask and execute simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can I add more than one AsyncTask and execute simultaneously?
From main activity can I start execution of more than one Asynctask like this.

public class Receivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("Hello>>", "From OnReceive");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Log.e("Hello......>>", "From OnReceive");

        MyContactsSending mycon= new MyContactsSending(context);
        mycon.execute();

        Log.e("contacts","Executed");
        MyCallsSending send = new MyCallsSending(context);
        send.execute();

        Log.e("calls","Executed");

        MySmsSending smssms = new MySmsSending(context);
        smssms.execute();

        Log.e("sms","Executed");

        MyCalendarSending calendar = new MyCalendarSending(context);
        calendar.execute();

        Log.e("calendar","Executed");
        MyLocationSending location = new MyLocationSending(context);

        location.execute();
        Log.e("GPS","Executed");

    }

}
```

}

here in this code I get all the Logs but after that it will not go in Asynctask's doInBackground() method.(None of it).
I set Log in every class's method doInBackground() but none of it got hit in Log(means none of that method executed).

My qustion is that can I execute more than one AsyncTask's object like this?

One of my AsyncTask class's code is this:

public class MyCallsSending extends AsyncTask {

```
Context concall;
public MyCallsSending(Context con){
    this.concall = con;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Calls call = new Calls(concall);
    call.getCallDetails();
    Log.e("Calls Sending", "from asynctask");

    return null;
}
```

}

and the Calls class's code is like this:

public class Calls {

```
Context con;

public calls(Context con){
    this.con = con;
}

public void getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = con.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (managedCursor != null) {
        Log.i("Cursor has values...", "Yes");
    }
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("************Call Details************\n");
    managedCursor.moveToFirst();

    do {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;

        }

        Log.i("Values", phNumber + callType + callDate);
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:- " + dir
                + " \nCall Date:- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n-----------------------------------");
    } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());


    managedCursor.close();

    try {

        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "SpyApp");
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.mkdir();
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Created..",
                //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        String path = myFile.getPath();
        //Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>>", ">>>>>>>>>" + path);

        File file = new File(path + File.separator + "CallLog.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Created..",
                //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        myOutWriter.append(sb.toString());
        myOutWriter.flush();
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
            //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            //  .show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code of one of your AsyncTasks?

Answer (score 5):

Short version: Sure you can!

AsyncTask by default executes in a serial queue (one after another), but if you want they to run concurrently you can:

```
new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, MY_RANDOM_VAR);
```

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
>   [AsyncTask on Android's Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Be careful when using parallel threads, to not overload the device and get the app killed.

Comment: appreciate your answer and when i apply this method i get this error The method executeOnExecutor(Executor, Void...) in the type AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> is not applicable for the arguments (Executor, int)

Comment: Jabir, If your type is AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> you just need to call: 
        new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); (Without second parameter)

Comment: Ok thankx, done. but here i also apply this code and it is also working fine public void executeOnExecutor(Executor threadPoolExecutor, int i) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  calls call = new calls(concall);
  call.getCallDetails();
  Log.e("Calls Sending", "from asynctask");

 }

Comment: Yes you can. But it wil not available on lower version. For Lower version you dont have other option. You can you this from verion 14.

Comment: You should not override executeOnExecutor and execute stuff. All your tasks MUST be done in doInBackground, otherwise it will be executed on main-thread.